# where exactly put using namespace std; and #include <iostream> (libraries) in my files

Tags: c++

when i start programming i use only one source code so i put libraries and namespace in the first of my code ... now i using two source code as one main and second to define functions(need `cout`,`cin`,any other impeded functions as `algorithm`'s) and a `header file` for prototype  ... finally i found a big annoy as i don't know where exactly put my includes and `using namespace std;`
to be used in a hall program not only in one source code ...

Comment: Better [not put `using namespace std` anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Bad idea, more often than not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want to avoid including the standard headers in so many places?

Comment: yes that's i mean i want to avoid including the standard headers in so many places